# Angular and JWT, redirect after authentication

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, jwt

I'm able to make the authentication using JWT and angular-jwt, but now how can i redirect the user to the home page including the token in the header request? I'm using Spring Boot for the server side and i'd like to know how to serve this request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the front-end's responsibility, you should redirect the user from angular, you can use the `$location` service.
as to the token you can store it in the `$rootScope` or in a client side cookie, here is an example of a jwt auth service i have wrote before it uses the `$rootScope` to store the client state.
note that this is not a production code.

```
app.service('AuthService', function ($rootScope, $http, $location) {
    var service = this;
    service.authenticate = function (credentials) {
        $http({
            'url': authUrl,
            'method': 'POST',
            'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            'data': credentials
        }).then(function (response) {
            if (response.data.token && response.data.token.length > 0) {
                $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                $rootScope.jwtToken = response.data.token;
                $location.path('/home');
            } else {
                $rootScope.logout();
            }
        }, function () {
            $rootScope.logout();
        });

        $rootScope.logout = service.logout;
    };

    service.isAuthenticated = function () {
        return $rootScope.authenticated;
    };

    service.logout = function () {
        $rootScope.authenticated = false;
        $rootScope.jwtToken = null;
    };
});
```